# calc package and global lengths problem in tabularx

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx, calculations, lengths

The output of the following code is affected whether `calc` package is included or not:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
% \usepackage{calc}
\newsavebox{\testbox}
\newlength{\testlen}

\newcommand{\boxx}[1]{%
 \savebox{\testbox}{#1}%
 \ifdim\wd\testbox>\testlen \global\setlength{\testlen}{\wd\testbox}\fi
 \parbox{\testlen}{#1}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{10cm}{|c|X|c|}
col 1 & col 2 & col 3 \\
\boxx{\mbox{}\hfill aaaaaaa\hfill\mbox{}} & xxxxxxxxxxxxx \par testlen value: \the\testlen & \boxx{bbbbbbbbbb} \\
\boxx{\mbox{}\hfill 50\hfill\mbox{}} & yyyyyyyyyyyy & \boxx{A\hfill1} \\
 90 & zzzzzzzzz & B\hfill2
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

I'm taking advantage of the three pass of `tabularx` to determine which cell has the widest text to set a global length with this value. On the second pass all cells will have a `parbox` using this length.

Without `calc`, everything works as expected. With `calc` the length is not globalized and has no effect opening `parbox`es on other cells.

What to do? I need `calc`.

The application of all this is [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295003/different-alignment-on-columns-when-the-x-column-wraps-in-tabularx). I'm solving this situation.

Comment: Why do you need package `calc`?

Comment: @Herbert because is a class that uses `pbox` package, which relies on `calc` package. I'm the author of that class (factura). Also I do some artithmetic on lengths based on `calc`, but the most important is the `pbox` package.

Comment: with `etex` which is nowadays part of every tex engine it is easier to use `\dimexpr` and `\numexpr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the macros from `calc`. However, I would use `\dimexpr` without package `calc`

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{tabularx}
 \usepackage{calc}
\newlength\testA
\newlength\testB

\newcommand\boxx[1]{%
    \settowidth{\testA}{#1}%
    \ifdim\testA>\testB \global\testB=\testA\fi
    \parbox{\testB}{#1}}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{10cm}{|c|X|c|}
        col 1 & col 2 & col 3 \\
        \boxx{\mbox{}\hfill aaaaaaa\hfill\mbox{}} & xxxxxxxxxxxxx \par testlen value: \the\testB & \boxx{bbbbbbbbbb} \\
        \boxx{\mbox{}\hfill 50\hfill\mbox{}} & yyyyyyyyyyyy & \boxx{A\hfill1} \\
        90 & zzzzzzzzz & B\hfill2
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course!! Pretty easy. Thank you @Herbert.

Answer (score 4):

```
\global\setlength{\testlen}{\wd\testbox}
```

has never been supported syntax.

Without the `calc` package it just happens to work by accident as `\setlength`  just expands to `\testlength=\wd\testbox\relax` so the construct is `\global\testlength=\wd\testbox\relax`

With `\calc` package, `\setlength` is a complicated macro that has to parse the infix `calc` syntax and does so making many intermediate definitions. So depending on just how lucky or unlucky you are the `\global` could end up not prefixing an assignment at all, so make an error, or end up prefixing some internal temporary assignment. It will not make the assignment to `\testlength` global in either case.