# Fill mutirow cell when the horizontal lines are drawn with \hhline

Tags: tables, multirow, colortbl, hhline

When I fill the multirow cell whose horizontal lines inside the cell are drawn with `\hhline{~}`, there will be blanks, I try to fix it by `>{\arrayrulecolor{gray}\doublerulesepcolor{gray}}=`, but the color of vertical lines will be messed also.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{dashrule}
\usepackage{ehhline}
\newcommand{\cdl}[2][black]{\leaders\hbox{\textcolor{#1}{\hdashrule{0.9mm}{#2}{0.3mm 0.3mm 0.3mm 0mm}}}\hfil}
\newcommand{\crs}[2][black]{\leaders\hbox{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{0.1pt}{#2}}}\hfil}
\newcommand{\vcl}[2][black]{\color{#1}\vrule width #2}
\setlength\doublerulesep{0.1pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{!{\vcl{3pt}}c!{\vcl[green]{3pt}}c!{\vcl[yellow]{3pt}}}
\hhline{
  !{\cdl[red]{1pt}}
  !{\crs[red]{1pt}}
}
  \multicolumn{1}{!{\vcl[green]{3pt}}c!{\vcl{2pt}}}{\cellcolor{gray}test}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c!{\vcl{3pt}}}{test}\\
\hhline{
  !{\cdl[orange]{1pt}}
  !{\crs[teal]{2pt}}
}
  \cellcolor{gray} & test\\
\hhline{
  >{\arrayrulecolor{gray}\doublerulesepcolor{gray}}%
  =%
  !{\crs[red]{1pt}}
}
    \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{gray} test some thing}
  & test\\
\hhline{
  !{\cdl[red]{1pt}}
  !{\crs[red]{1pt}}
}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]
I nearly successed by set hhline to

```
\hhline{
  >{\rule{3pt}{1pt} \kern -3pt \arrayrulecolor{gray}\doublerulesepcolor{gray}}%
  =
  !{\crs[red]{1pt}}
}
```

but there is a small blank sep.
[image]

#### Solved but why?

I solve the problem, but I don't know why this will work

```
\hhline{
  >{\rule{3pt}{1pt} \kern -3.3pt \arrayrulecolor{gray}\doublerulesepcolor{gray}}%
  =
  >{\kern -3pt \textcolor{green}{\rule{3pt}{1pt}}}%
  !{\crs[red]{1pt}}
}
```

I just need change the width of the rule to make it the same with the width of the vertical line, but what are `-3.3pt` and `-3pt` represent?

Comment: My feeling is that you're doing a drawing task in the form of a table rather than a real table with colored cells. In this case, why not use TikZ directly? It is very powerful and relatively easy, with great documentation.

Comment: Because I am writing a script tool to convert excel to latex, so I have to perfect the details as well as I can.

Comment: @jsbibra It is possible to draw latex table with the same style that is in excel. I nearly make it. If you have some interests, see https://github.com/ZhiyuanLck/excel2tex

Comment: specify a black  `|` in the hhline  before the grey `-`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Do not use syntax `\global\setlength ...`, it has never been supported. (see [explanation here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/297189/79060)). To change a length globally, `etoolbox`'s `\deflength` is your friend. It shares the same (usual) syntax with `\setlength` while supports the extra `\global\deflength` usage.

---

The width of vline is 3pt (due to the `!{\vcl{3pt}}` used in tabular preamble), but a `|` used in `\hhline` only adds a rule of width `\arrarrulewidth`. Change the `\arrayfulewidth` locally could be a workaround, while providing a new `\hhline` preamble character, like what `ehhline` package does, is more elegant.

```
% \usepackage{etoolbox}

\hhline{
  >{\global\deflength{\arrayrulewidth}{3pt}} |
  >{\global\deflength{\arrayrulewidth}{.4pt}\arrayrulecolor{gray}\doublerulesepcolor{gray}} =
  >{\global\deflength{\arrayrulewidth}{3pt}\arrayrulecolor{green}} |
  !{\crs[red]{1pt}}
  >{\arrayrulecolor{yellow}} |
}
% restore \arrayrulewidth for following use
\global\deflength{\arrayrulewidth}{.4pt}%
```

The `\global` is required since the `\HH@loop` redefined by `colortbl` adds an extra group of curly braces. Related code lines:

```
% from colortbl.sty
\def\HH@loop{%
  ... ...
  \ifx\@tempb|\if@tempswa
        \ifx\CT@drsc@\relax
         \HH@add{\hskip\doublerulesep}%
        \else
         \HH@add{{\CT@drsc@\vrule\@width\doublerulesep}}%
         \fi
        \fi\@tempswatrue
        %% \vline is just "\vrule \@width \arrayrulewidth"
        \HH@add{{\CT@arc@\vline}}\else
  ... ...
}
```

Note that since `hhline` v2.04 (2020/01/04), space token used inside `\hhline` is always ignored.

---

In the following example, the `\HH@loop` is patched to allow use of `V[<color>]{<width>}` inside `\hhline{..}`. This may shorten the length of arguments of `\hhline` in OP's example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}
% \usepackage{colortbl} % or uncomment this line
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{xpatch} % or etoolbox
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
% based on \vline from latex2e
\def\HHvline#1{\vrule\@width#1}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \@ifpackageloaded{colortbl}{
    % based on \ifx\@tempb|...\else part of \HH@loop from colortbl.sty
    \NewDocumentCommand{\HH@preamble@V}{ m o m }{%
      \if@tempswa
        \ifx\CT@drsc@\relax
          \HH@add{\hskip\doublerulesep}%
        \else
          \HH@add{{\CT@drsc@\vrule\@width\doublerulesep}}%
        \fi
      \fi
      \@tempswatrue
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\HH@add{{\CT@arc@{\HHvline{#3}}}}}
        {\HH@add{{\color{#2}\HHvline{#3}}}}%
      \HH@let V%
    }
    \xpatchcmd\HH@loop
      {\PackageWarning{hhline}}
      {%
        \ifx\@tempb V% V[<color>]{<width>}
          \let\next\HH@preamble@V
        \else
        \PackageWarning{hhline}%
      }
      {}{\fail}
  }{
    % based on \ifx\@tempb|...\else part of \HH@loop from hhline.sty
    \NewDocumentCommand{\HH@preamble@V}{ m o m }{%
      \if@tempswa\HH@add{\hskip\doublerulesep}\fi\@tempswatrue
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\HH@add{\@tempc{\HHvline{#3}}\@tempc}}
        {\HH@add{\@tempc{\color{#2}\HHvline{#3}}\@tempc}}%
      \HH@let V%
    }
    \xpatchcmd\HH@loop
      {\PackageWarning{hhline}}
      {%
        \ifx\@tempb V% V[<color>]{<width>}
          \let\next\HH@preamble@V
        \else
      }
      {}{\fail}
  }
  \xpatchcmd\HH@loop
    {\fi\fi\fi}
    {\fi\fi\fi\fi}
    {}{\fail}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{!{\HHvline{1pt}}c!{\HHvline{2pt}}c!{\HHvline{3pt}}}
  \hline
  a & b \\ \hhline{V[red]{1pt} = V[blue]{2pt} = V[green]{3pt}}
  c & d \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes thanks I was going to suggest the global but then noticed that the OP was using ehhline which I hadn't seen before so got sidetracked checking that package:-) .  I haven't traced exactly what ehhline is doing but I'd have thought `!{\vrule width 3pt}`  would have worked (but it does not:(

Comment: Ah `ehhline` is a small package newly uploaded to CTAN. It adds `!{...}`, which acts like a `-` but accepts leader, to the hhline preamble.

Comment: Yes and it makes `!` a complete cell (it adds `&`)  the functionality is OK but I wouldn't have used `!` as that is unlike `!` from array package, hmmmm

Comment: @ZhiyuanLck Answer is updated to show a new hhline preamble char, "V[<color>]{<width>}". Hope that would help.