# Is hvfloat incompatible with mathtools and cellspace?

Tags: graphics, incompatibility, mathtools, cellspace

I notice strange interaction between the `hvfloat` package and the `cellspace` and `mathtools` packages.

It happens when I want to split an image (png or pdf) on two pages via the command `\hvFloat[doublePage]{...}{...}{...}{...}`.

If neither `cellspace` nor `mathtools` is loaded, there is no problem, the image, whether it is in png or pdf format, is well and truly split in two:

[image]
[image]

However, if either `mathtools` or `cellspace` package is loaded, `hvfloat` no longer works properly. The images are no longer split in two, a thin black band appears on the first page, and one half of the image appears shifted on the second page:

[image]
[image]

Are these packages incompatible?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=2cm, outer=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, lipsum, hvfloat}

% hvfloat will not work properly if any of these packages is loaded:
% \usepackage{cellspace}
% \usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]

\hvFloat[doublePage, bindCorr=inner]%
    {figure}%
    {\includegraphics[width=32cm]{Test.pdf}}%
    {First image.}%
    {fig1}

\lipsum[1-15]

\hvFloat[doublePage, bindCorr=inner]%
    {figure}%
    {\includegraphics[width=32cm]{Test.png}}%
    {Second image.}%
    {fig2}

\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

For the png and pdf images used in the MWE, they are simply black rectangles of 32 cm wide and 16 cm high. The pdf image `Test.pdf` can simply be produced as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw (0,0) rectangle (32,16);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here is the png image `Test.png`:
[image]

Comment: both packages load calc, and hvfloat uses `\global\setlength{\@dblfptop}{0\p@}` which is wrong and doesn't work with calc. see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/297189/2388. That is a clear bug in hvfloat and should be reported.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your answer, indeed, by making the appropriate substitutions in the package code, everything works. I have contacted the author of the package.

Comment: I'll fix it as soon as possible ...